# ajax javascript 500 error

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is the javascript for a simple multifile upload.

This javascript works on my development server no problem. But when I put it on my production server I get a 500 error on the AJAX Post. Could this be because I have to edit php.ini more? or are there other problems?

```
var app = app || {};

(function(o){
"use strict";

var ajax, getFormData, setProgress;

ajax = function(data){
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(), uploaded;

  xmlhttp.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(){
     if(this.readyState ===4){

        if(this.status===200){
           //console.log('here');
           uploaded = JSON.parse(this.response);
           if(typeof o.options.finished==='function'){
              o.options.finished(uploaded);
           }
        }else{
           if(typeof o.options.error ==='function'){
              o.options.error();
           }
        }            
     }
  });

  xmlhttp.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event){
     var percent;
     if (event.lengthComputable ===true){
        percent = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total)*100);
        //console.log(percent);
        setProgress(percent);
     }
  });

  xmlhttp.open('post', o.options.processor);
  xmlhttp.send(data);
};
getFormData = function(source){
  var data = new FormData(), i;

  for( i=0;i<source.length;i=i+1){
     data.append('file[]',source[i]);
  }
  data.append('ajax',true);
  return data;
 };

 setProgress = function(value){
  if(o.options.progressBar !== undefined){
     o.options.progressBar.style.width=value? value + '%': 0; 
  }
  if(o.options.progressText !== undefined){
     o.options.progressText.innerText=value? value + '%': ''; 
  }
 };
 o.uploader = function(options){
  o.options = options;

  if(o.options.files!== undefined){
     ajax(getFormData(o.options.files.files));
  }
 };
}(app));
```

Comment: An HTTP '500' error is an error on the server itself, so your AJAX Post is reaching the server fine - the error lies in the response.

Comment: How would you suggest I fix it?

Comment: yup, what @Widor says. check your weblogs, fix the issue (and test the url by opening it up in the browser normally), when it works get back to your javascript piece again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

giorgio helped me get on the right track
I was using `$uploaded = [];` in my php, if I am not mistaken this is old PHP and the correct way is `$uploaded = array();` I am using about 5 array and I guess that XAMP is so lenient that it will run what ever I give to it.